# Redirect to another react page and pass axios result

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router

I am completing a project where after the user is logged in, I need to redirect him to "/me" page and show the result of axios login request. Could you please help me with this, here is the code snippet

```
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.status === 200) {
          setMessage("Logged in successfully");
          axios
            .get("http://someip/me", {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${res.data.body.access_token}`,
              },
            })
            .then((res) => {
              console.log(res);
              return <Redirect to="/me" />;
            });
        }
      });
```

Comment: then what's the problem?

Comment: @Jerson The first thing is that it is not redirecting to another page and also I do not know how can I pass the result to that page

Answer (score 1):

You can the store the data in the local/session storage to use it further

```
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.status === 200) {
      setMessage("Logged in successfully");
      axios
        .get("http://someip/me", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${res.data.body.access_token}`,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          localStorage.setItem('myItem', res);
          return <Redirect to="/me" />;
        });
    }
  });
```